# Missing texture coordinates for channel 0 Fbx and XNA 4.0

Tags: xna, textures, xna-4.0, models, maya

I'm getting this error while trying to load a model in XNA 4.0 :
Error   2   The mesh "transform1", using SkinnedEffect, contains geometry that is missing texture coordinates for channel 0.
The model was dxf format then I upload it to maya then I added some skeleton and some texture (viewed it on the UV) but I still get this error.

[image]

this is the load function.

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Load the model.
        currentModel = Content.Load<Model>("myModel");

        // Look up our custom skinning information.
        SkinningData skinningData = currentModel.Tag as SkinningData;

        if (skinningData == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException
                ("This model does not contain a SkinningData tag.");

        // Create an animation player, and start decoding an animation clip.
        animationPlayer = new AnimationPlayer(skinningData);

        AnimationClip clip = skinningData.AnimationClips["Take 001"];

        animationPlayer.StartClip(clip);
    }
```

this is the draw function :

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice device = graphics.GraphicsDevice;

        device.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Matrix[] bones = animationPlayer.GetSkinTransforms();

        // Compute camera matrices.
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -40, 0) * // x, y, z
                      Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraRotation)) * //rotate y
                      Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraArc)) * //rotate x
                      Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -cameraDistance), 
                                          new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);

        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
                                                                device.Viewport.AspectRatio,
                                                                1,
                                                                10000);


        // Render the skinned mesh.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in currentModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (SkinnedEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.SetBoneTransforms(bones);

                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;

                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.25f);
                effect.SpecularPower = 16;

            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

PS : 1-My knowledge with Maya & XNA is very limited cause I used to use OpenGL/C++ for some time.

2-Also I change my Content Processor to SkinnedModelProcessor not Model - XNA Framework.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear. One of your meshes/vertices is missing a texture coordinate, which is the expectation in this case. In Maya, apply a texture channel to `transform1` mesh even if you have no intentions of assigning any textures to it.

Also, why do you have a mesh called "transform"? Are you sure you didn't mistakenly misname a bone as mesh or vice versa?

Comment: I'll try this out, sorry it wasn't my model and didn't check the name. thanks .

Comment: Thanks very much, I did the mapping and changed the name and everything is great, also sorry if the question was repetitive or dumb.